# QML: How to do variables?

Tags: application-development, programming, qt, qml, qt-creator

In QML, I am just looking for a way to do fairly simple variables:

1. Bool
2. String
3. Integer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use QML basic types or the generic [var](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-var.html) property.

> The var type is a generic property type that can refer to any data
>   type.
>
> It is equivalent to a regular JavaScript variable. For example, var
>   properties can store numbers, strings, objects, arrays and functions.

The following code will demonstrate the use of both basic types and var properties:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1

Rectangle {
    id: mainView
    width: units.gu(30) 
    height: units.gu(40)

    Item {
        id: myItem
        property int aNumber: 100
        property bool aBool: false
        property string aString: "Hello world!"
        property var aVarNumber: 100
        property var aVarBool: false
        property var aVarString: "Hello world!"
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log(myItem.aNumber, myItem.aVarNumber)
        console.log(myItem.aBool, myItem.aVarBool)
        console.log(myItem.aString, myItem.aVarString)
    }
}
```

Source: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-typesystem-basictypes.html